# Pyomo CBC non-zero return code (-6) error

Tags: python, exe, pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I have a optimization script which works fine in a jupyter notebook, however when I converted into a python script I get this cbc error? I've tried many things, still can't figure out what's causing this unsual error?

```
ERROR: Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (-6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/t/file.py", line 109, in <module>
    opt.solve(model, strategy='GOA', mip_solver='cbc', threads=4)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/MindtPy.py", line 113, in solve
    return SolverFactory(_supported_algorithms[config.strategy][0]).solve(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/algorithm_base_class.py", line 2804, in solve
    self.MindtPy_iteration_loop(config)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/algorithm_base_class.py", line 2889, in MindtPy_iteration_loop
    main_mip, main_mip_results = self.solve_main(config)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/algorithm_base_class.py", line 1670, in solve_main
    main_mip_results = mainopt.solve(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 627, in solve
    raise ApplicationError("Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: Solver (cbc) did not exit normally
```